# Disable a specific option boostrap-multiselect

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-multiselect

---

### Question

I want to disable a single option with JS. I tried using the following code:

```
var input = $('input[value="' + selectedPriLang + "Sec" + '"]');
        input.prop('disabled', false);
        input.parent('li').addClass('disabled');
```

It kind of works, but the problem is I can still enable the option using the Select all button.
Also, not sure if relevant, I execute the code in a onChange from a different multiselect.

```
<select id="sel_secLang" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="nlSec" disabled="disabled">Dutch</option>
        <option value="enSec">English</option>
        <option value="deSec">German</option>
        <option value="FrSec">French</option>
</select>
```

Hope this explanation is clear enough, first question ;D.

---

### Answer

Although Joe's answer worked I tried it out myself, For disabling:

```
var input = $('input[value="' + selectedPriLang + "Sec" + '"]');
input.prop('disabled', true);
var input2 = input.parent('label').parent('a').parent('li');
input4.removeClass('active');
input4.addClass('disabled');
```

For enabling:

```
var input = $('input[value="' + selectedPriLang + "Sec" + '"]');
input.prop('disabled', false);
var input2 = input.parent('label').parent('a').parent('li');
input2.removeClass('disabled');
```

Just the value of the input
    selectedPriLang = $('#sel_priLang option:selected').val();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a quick note to clarify: disabling the corresponding checkbox and adding the `.disabled` class to the appropriate `li` is not sufficient. You also have to disable the underlying `option`. Example (can also be found in the [documentation](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/)):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example-disable-javascript').multiselect({
            includeSelectAllOption: true
        });

        $('#example-disable-javascript-disable').on('click', function() {
            var input = $('#example-disable-javascript-container input[value="3"]');
            var option = $('#example-disable-javascript-container option[value="3"]');

            input.prop('disabled', true);
            option.prop('disabled', true);

            input.parent('label').parent('a').parent('li').addClass('disabled');
        });

        $('#example-disable-javascript-check').on('click', function() {
            var options = '';
            $('#example-disable-javascript option:selected').each(function() {
                options += $(this).val() + ', ';
            });

            alert(options.substr(0, options.length - 2));
        });
    });
</script>
<div class="btn-group" id="example-disable-javascript-container">
    <select id="example-disable-javascript" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
        <option value="3">Option 3</option>
        <option value="4">Option 4</option>
        <option value="5">Option 5</option>
        <option value="6">Option 6</option>
    </select>
    <button id="example-disable-javascript-disable" class="btn btn-primary">Disable an option!</button>
    <button id="example-disable-javascript-check" class="btn btn-primary">Check</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to process the disabled events in an on-change handler on you're own and de-select them when the select-all is picked. Generally the process could look like:

- Capture on selection event for select all
- Iterate on elements
- Remove the checked attribute for the disabled elements

Something along the lines of capturing on change, find disabled, and unchecking them:

```
$('#sel_secLang').multiselect({
        onChange: function(option, checked, select) {
            $('input[type=checkbox]:disabled').each(checkbox, function(){
                 checkbox.attr('checked', false);
             });
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hey that worked! But I was irritated that it didn't work the way I wanted it to work,  So I tried disabling the class instead of the input. That worked. Check the question if interested.